# Unload .vdproj (visual studio deployment project) from visual studio 2010 solution

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, deployment-project

I have a solution under source control, one of the projects in it is vdproj (Visual Studio Deployment Project) or setup project, this project gives me very annoying tens of messages every time i try to build the solution

```
---------------------------
Microsoft Visual Studio
---------------------------
The command you are attempting cannot be completed because the file 'XXXXInstaller.vdproj' is under source code control and is not checked out.
---------------------------
OK   Help   
---------------------------
```

[image: Visual Studio Error Message - VDProj Error]

The question is: How to unload this project from the solution, when i try to unload it, there are no such option in the right-click context menu!

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@MSS, as a work around you can edit the solution file by commenting the corresponding .vdproj project.

Answer (score 10):

I've found [the issue raised on Microsoft Connect](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/288663/no-unload-project-on-context-menu-with-right-clicking-setup-project-in-solution-explorer). It seems that "unload" is supported, but just not shown on the context menu. In other words, selecting the project and using the normal "Project" menu (next to "View") still shows the option "Unload project".

Another idea: If you keep your the deployment projects in a solution folder, you can use "Unload all projects in solution folder" from the context menu provided by the [Microsoft Productivity Power Tools](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/d0d33361-18e2-46c0-8ff2-4adea1e34fef).

Answer (score 2):

You can also select multiple projects in Solution Explorer (you will be able to unload at least one of them) and unload them. Then reload required projects.